# ReEntrantLcoks-What is the use of having multiple locks on the same object

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

While going through the advantages of `ReEntrantLock` one of them is:

> With ReentrantLock, a thread can acquire lock on the same object more
>   than once.

I came across this answer which states that there would be a deadlock in the `get(index)`. Can someone please explain how can a deadlock occur at that point, if we are not using any `synchronization` on `get(index)`?

[UseCase of multiple locks on same object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596239/1337007)

Comment: That's weird, how would you deadlock at method that's not even implemented

Comment: Looks like a misprint. If lock is not repentant then you would deadlock at `set()` not `get()`. Also every recursive synchronized method will also deadlock if using non-reentrant lock.